# JPA Merge and Remove are not cascaded to child object at the same time

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence, openjpa

I'm using Open JPA in the commercial project and would like to take advantage of the cascading Parent->Child remove and merge.

I mocked up a working code which shows the issues.

I have a persistent Parent object with some children. I'm eliminating one of the Children's relation and passing detached Parent to merge. When transaction is committed a UPDATE statement issued, trying to update orphaned child with NULL foreign key.

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
        private String desc;
    //@ElementDependent
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", 
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}/*,orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER*/)
        private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @Id private String desc;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;


    public class StackOverflowTest extends TestCase {
        private EntityManager em;
        private static EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SSICTest", System.getProperties());
        private Parent p;
        private Child c;
        private Child c2;

        public void testRemove() {
            prepareObjects();

            startTr();
            em.persist(p);
            commitTr();

            startTr();
            p = em.find(Parent.class, p.getId());
            em.remove(p);
            commitTr();
        }   
        public void testMerge() {
            prepareObjects();

            startTr();
            em.persist(p);
            commitTr();

            //remove on detached
            Child child = p.getChilds().get(0);
            p.getChilds().remove(child);
            child.setParent(null);
            startTr();

            em.merge(p);
            commitTr();

            startTr();
            p = em.find(Parent.class, p.getId());
            assertEquals(1, p.getChilds().size());
            commitTr();
        }
        protected void prepareObjects() {
            p = new Parent();       
            c = new Child();
            c2 = new Child();
            p.setDesc("desc");
            c.setDesc(Math.random()+"");
            c2.setDesc(Math.random()+"");
            p.getChilds().add(c);
            c.setParent(p);
            p.getChilds().add(c2);
            c2.setParent(p);
        }   
        void commitTr() {
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        }
        void startTr() {
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
        }
    }
```

In the example above testRemove works fine but testMerge method not, as I described at the top.

If I remove comment on @ElementDependent it works different.

testRemove fails, because remove not cascaded to Child and referential integrity exception thrown by db, and testMerge is fine.

orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER or    @ForeignKey(deleteAction=ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE) on inverse relation in child
do not help too.

Please advise. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Hi Lars! I added this, but no help
`@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="ID")
 private Parent parent;`

Comment: where is your current mapping setup? is it in the persistence.xml file? Otherwise to my knowledge there some more annotations needed to get the mapping working. Where are the information to which db columns the attributes are mapped? (btw dont use "desc" as attribute name, as it is a reserved SQL word)

Comment: yes, mappings are in persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", 
    cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE},
    orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<Child>();

 @ManyToOne
 private Parent parent;
```

Set orphanRemoval to true.[See purpose of orphanRemoval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/giqxy/index.html)

Comment: Setting orphanRemoval to true does not work, as I mentioned.
UPDATE statement issued, trying to update orphaned child with NULL foreign key in testMerge method!